# How to properly install nvidia drivers in Debian

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have the following configuration:

```
root@bitthunder:~# lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I have tried installing nvidia drivers from website, manual, bumblebee after I install them when trying to test it I get only

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

Bumblebee is saying it cannot start device on PCI:01. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the `bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia` drivers? See https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee. Please specify your laptop model, and Debian version/release.

Comment: @FaheemMitha if you read my post you would see that I already tried installed bumblebee, also I specified the hardware that I use. The laptop is a no name so I don't think model would be any use. I use debian 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Debian has packages for the [nvidia-driver](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/nvidia-driver) have you tried using them? In case you can't find them make sure that there is a repository with non-free Software activated in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: yes I have tried installing them, same result as installing from nvidia website...no luck same errors. I think the problem is more deep than that.